# Does closed channel send value zero?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func asChan(vs ...int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, v := range vs {
            c <- v
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}

func merge(a, b <-chan int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-a:
                c <- v
            case v := <-b:
                c <- v
            }
        }
    }()

    return c
}

func main() {
    a := asChan(1, 3, 5, 7)
    b := asChan(2, 4, 6, 8)

    c := merge(a, b)

    for value := range c {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

---

below is the value zero for `v` received after closing channel `a`.

### [image]

but my understanding is, this line of code(`case v := <-a:`) in `merge()` function should block for input, because the channel(`a`) is closed

**Edit:**

After code changes, `main()` does not exit:

```
func merge(a, b <-chan int) chan int {
    c := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        defer close(c)

        for a != nil || b != nil { // while atleast one channel is open
            select {
            case v, ok := <-a:
                sendOnChannel(a, c, v, ok)
            case v, ok := <-b:
                sendOnChannel(b, c, v, ok)
            }
        }
    }()

    return c
}

func sendOnChannel(sourceChan <-chan int, targetChan chan int, v int, channelOpen bool) {
    if !channelOpen {
        // The channel is closed. Set channel variable
        // to nil to disable this select / case.
        sourceChan = nil
    } else {
        targetChan <- v
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ bin/cs61a 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

---

How `a` generates zero in this line of code(`case v := <-a`)?

Comment: The edit copies from my answer, but omits an important detail:  the local variable `a` and `b` are set to nil when receive yields zero, false.

Comment: @CeriseLimón In your code `c` is receive-only(`<-chan int`) channel, so we cannot write(`c <- v`) to channel `c`. Query edited.

Comment: The variable `c` is not receive only in my code.  Try my code here: https://play.golang.org/p/QZGmRC816tp.  The latest edit misses the important detail of setting the local variables `a` and `b` to nil.

Comment: @CeriseLimón In your code, `merge()` has return type `<-chan int` which is receive only, which contradicts with `c <- v`

Comment: The return type of the function is not relevant to the use of the local variable `c` in the function. The code in the answer compiles and runs.  If you encountered a problem compiling or running the code, then please describe what actually happened.

Comment: @CeriseLimón In this code(https://play.golang.org/p/G9ZTgv79aj3), program does not exit.

Comment: Your code in the playground has the same problem as the two edits to the question.  The code does not set local variables `a` and `b` in `merge` to `nil`.  The values of variables `a` an `b` are not changed by setting local variable `soruceChan` in function `sendOnChannel`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón In this code(https://play.golang.org/p/wseXPNGyQ6H) am unable to set channels to nil, after passing to a function. Is channel passed to a function like a slice header(pointer,len,cap)?

Comment: Channel arguments are passed as values like all other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator):

> A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any previously sent values have been received.

I don't know why the language designers chose this design, but it's useful in practice.

Use the two-value receive statement to detect when the channel yields a zero value because the channel is closed.

```
v, ok := <-a
if !ok {
   // channel closed
}
```

Use the following code to implement merge:

```
func merge(a, b <-chan int) <-chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(c)

        // While we have at least one channel ...

        for a != nil || b != nil {
            select {
            case v, ok := <-a:
                if ok {
                    c <- v
                } else {
                    // The channel is closed. Set channel variable
                    // to nil to disable this select / case.
                    a = nil 
                }
            case v, ok := <-b:
                if ok {
                    c <- v
                } else {
                    b = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    return c
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QZGmRC816tp).

Comment: `close(ch)` is generally used to broadcast message to multiple go-routines. But above scenario generating zero value is confusing to understand the building blocks

Comment: I am sorry, but that's the way the language is designed.  Use two-value receive.

Comment: @overexchange `close(ch)` is used to record that no more values will be sent.  Broadcasting a state change to multiple goroutines is just one use of this feature.